# Cycle in Merge K-Sorted LinkedLists

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, merge

My merge k-sorted lists algorithm uses divide and conquer and utilizes merge 2 lists algorithm as a helper in the process.

The issue lies is during an iteration a cycle is created and I can't figure out why.

I traced down the code to the exact place where this happen, but I am still unable to discern the issue.

```
class Solution {
public:

    ListNode* mergeTwoLists(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2, bool debug=false) 
    {
        ListNode *head = new ListNode(-1);
        ListNode *curr = head;

        while(l1 && l2) 
        {   

          if(l1->val <= l2->val)
            {
                curr->next = l1;
                l1 = l1->next;
            }
            else
            {
                curr->next = l2; 
                l2 = l2->next;

            }
            curr = curr->next;

        }
        // some list may be still populated
        l1 != NULL ? curr->next = l1 : curr->next = l2;
        return head->next;
    }


    ListNode* mergeKLists(std::vector<ListNode*>& lists) 
    {
        // approach of divide and conquer
        int size = lists.size();
        int interval = 1;
        int tmp_val = 1;
        bool debug= false;
        while(interval < size)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<size-interval; i*=2)
            {

                lists[i] = mergeTwoLists(lists[i], lists[i+interval], debug=debug);
                if (i==0)
                    i++;
            }
            interval*=2;
        }

        if (size)
            return lists[0];
        else
        {
            ListNode* ret=NULL;
            return ret;
        }

    }


};
```

For some reason this input [[-10,-9,-9,-3,-1,-1,0],[-5],[4],[-8],[],[-9,-6,-5,-4,-2,2,3],[-3,-3,-2,-1,0]]
provokes an infinite loop.

I get an infinite loop in the second list parameter to the sort 2 lists algorithm.
I believe it happens in some iteration in the lines of code:

```
                curr->next = l2;  
                l2 = l2->next;
```

Can somebody give me any hints?

Comment: You've been told before about [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your `mergeTwoLists` modifies the two lists passed to it, in such a way that they can come out of it sharing nodes. This would not be a problem (at least not a *big* problem) if you made sure to set one of them aside and never use it again.

Clearly that's what you intend with the index-juggling in `mergeKLists`, but there's a bug: you increase `i` incorrectly. You reuse a list you shouldn't, call `mergeTwoLists` on two lists that share a node, it creates a loop in the list and iterates forever.

The quick-and-dirty solution is to fix the index arithmetic in `mergeKLists`. The deeper solution is to be more careful with the pointers in `mergeTwoLists` so that two lists that go in disjoint come out disjoint.